# Width of a \schembox inside schemata

Tags: width, schemata

[image]I have this diagram

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Support for more character glyphs
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %per interpretare tutti i caratteri
\usepackage{schemata}%to set curly brackets nested
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\Schema{-15ex}{30ex}
{
  \schemabox{\textsc{codice di}\\ \textsc{ procedura}\\ \textsc{ penale} }
}%left-hand side parenthesis
{
  \schema{\schemabox{\textsc{libro I}\\ \textbf{Soggetti}}}%
{
      \Schema {-0.5ex}{3ex}{\schemabox{Titolo II\\Pubblico ministero}}
                            {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}\item art. 50 Azione penale \item art. 51 Uffici del p.m.  
              \end{itemize}} }
      \Schema {-0.5ex}{7.5ex}{\schemabox{Titolo III\\Polizia giudiziaria}}
                            {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}\item art. 55 Funzioni della p.g.  \item art. 56 Servizi e sezioni della p.g. \item art. 57 Ufficiali ed agenti di p.g. \item art. 58 Disponibilità della p.g. \item art. 59 Subordinazione della p.g. 
              \end{itemize}} }
      %\bigskip
            {
      \Schema {-0.5ex}{3ex} {\schemabox{Titolo IV\\Imputato}}
              {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--} \item art.60 Assunzione della qualità d'imputato \item art.61 Estensione dei diritti  e garanzie dell'imputato \item art.62 Assunzione della qualità d'imputato
              \end{itemize}} }
       }%1
 \bigskip
      {
      \schema {\schemabox{atti ricerca ed \\assicurazione del-\\la \textbf{ prova}}}
              {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--} \item \emph{accertamenti urgenti\\(art. 354 c.p.p.)} \item perquisizioni \item \emph{sequestri (art. 354 c.p.p.)}
              \end{itemize}} }
       }%1       
   }
  }% right-hand side parenthesis
\caption{Gli atti tipici dell'attività di iniziativa della p.g. }
\label{fig:attività p.g.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and I'm trying to set the width of the left hand side of the second braces all at the same width of "pubblico ministero" but I'm doing someting wrong. May I have some help?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Support for more character glyphs
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %per interpretare tutti i caratteri
\usepackage{schemata}%to set curly brackets nested    

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\Schema{-15ex}{30ex}
{\schemabox{\textsc{codice di}\\ \textsc{ procedura}\\ \textsc{ penale} }}%left-hand side parenthesis
{
\newbox\mybox\setbox\mybox =\hbox{Pubblico ministero  } 
\dimen0 =\wd\mybox
  \schema{\schemabox[\ dimen0]{\textsc{libro I}\\ \textbf{Soggetti}}}%
{
      \Schema {-0.5ex}{3ex}{\schemabox[\ dimen0]{Titolo II\\Pubblico ministero}}
                            {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}\item art. 50 Azione penale \item art. 51 Uffici del p.m.  
              \end{itemize}} }
      \Schema {-0.5ex}{7.5ex}{\schemabox[\ dimen0]{Titolo III\\Polizia giudiziaria}}
                            {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}\item art. 55 Funzioni della p.g.  \item art. 56 Servizi e sezioni della p.g. \item art. 57 Ufficiali ed agenti di p.g. \item art. 58 Disponibilità della p.g. \item art. 59 Subordinazione della p.g. 
              \end{itemize}} }
      %\bigskip
            {
      \Schema {-0.5ex}{3ex} [\ dimen0]{\schemabox{Titolo IV\\Imputato}}
              {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--} \item art.60 Assunzione della qualità d'imputato \item art.61 Estensione dei diritti  e garanzie dell'imputato \item art.62 Assunzione della qualità d'imputato
              \end{itemize}} }
       }%1
 \bigskip
      {
      \schema {\schemabox[\ dimen0]{atti ricerca ed \\assicurazione del-\\la \textbf{ prova}}}
              {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--} \item \emph{accertamenti urgenti\\(art. 354 c.p.p.)} \item perquisizioni \item \emph{sequestri (art. 354 c.p.p.)}
              \end{itemize}} }
       }%1       
   }
  }% right-hand side parenthesis
\caption{Gli atti tipici dell'attività di iniziativa della p.g. }
\label{fig:attività p.g.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'm using the example at 2.5 of the package documentation.

Comment: You can measure the width of a text uwing the `calc` package and something like the following: `\newlength{\mydimension}
\setlength{\mydimension}{\widthof{Pubblico ministero}}`. However, you might want to keep in mind that, although latex does not give any overfull box warnings, your diagram is a lot wider than the textwidth.

Comment: Part of the problem with that final example is that the whole manual for the schemata package is written to be doable in plain TeX as well as in LaTeX, which is kind of a pain for straight-up LaTeX users and may be a defect of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fix that does it more the LaTeX way. I tested it and it seems to do what you want. The problem with the schemata package is that it is quick, dirty, and unhelpful. But if you want a bare-bones thing that you can drop parboxes, or whatever the heck else you want and get math mode to put big braces and other stuff around it, it is easier than doing it totally from scratch.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Support for more character glyphs
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %per interpretare tutti i caratteri
\usepackage{schemata}%to set curly brackets nested
\begin{document}

\newlength\boxwidth
\newbox\mybox\setbox\mybox=\hbox{Pubblico ministero  }
\setlength{\boxwidth}{\wd\mybox}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\Schema{-15ex}{30ex}
{
  \schemabox{\textsc{codice di}\\ \textsc{ procedura}\\ \textsc{ penale} }
}%left-hand side parenthesis
{
  \schema{\schemabox{\textsc{libro I}\\ \textbf{Soggetti}}}%
{
      \Schema {-0.5ex}{3ex}{\schemabox[\boxwidth]{Titolo II\\Pubblico ministero}}
                        {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}\item art. 50 Azione penale \item art. 51 Uffici del p.m.  
          \end{itemize}} }
  \Schema {-0.5ex}{7.5ex}{\schemabox[\boxwidth]{Titolo III\\Polizia giudiziaria}}
                        {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}\item art. 55 Funzioni della p.g.  \item art. 56 Servizi e sezioni della p.g. \item art. 57 Ufficiali ed agenti di p.g. \item art. 58 Disponibilità della p.g. \item art. 59 Subordinazione della p.g. 
          \end{itemize}} }
  %\bigskip
        {
  \Schema {-0.5ex}{3ex} {\schemabox[\boxwidth]{Titolo IV\\Imputato}}
          {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--} \item art.60 Assunzione della qualità d'imputato \item art.61 Estensione dei diritti  e garanzie dell'imputato \item art.62 Assunzione della qualità d'imputato
          \end{itemize}} }
   }%1
 \bigskip
  {
  \schema {\schemabox[\boxwidth]{atti ricerca ed \\assicurazione del-\\la \textbf{ prova}}}
          {\vbox{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]\renewcommand\labelitemi{--} \item \emph{accertamenti urgenti\\(art. 354 c.p.p.)} \item perquisizioni \item \emph{sequestri (art. 354 c.p.p.)}
          \end{itemize}} }
   }%1       
   }
  }% right-hand side parenthesis
\caption{Gli atti tipici dell'attività di iniziativa della p.g. }
\label{fig:attività p.g.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```